# Is it possible to create a new thread under a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have a question: can man create a new `thread tt` under a `thread t`? This new `thread tt` needs to use a member function `memberfunction()` in `class A`. The `thread t` calls a independent function `D()` out of `class A`. The function `D()` calls the `memberfunction()` .

These are my rough code:

```
class A
{
public:
  int memberfunction();
};

void D ()
{
  A class;
  boost::function<int()> f;
  f = boost::bind(&A::memberfunction, &class);   
  boost::thread tt(f);
}

void main()
{
  ...
  boost::thread t(D);
}
```

the step `boost::thread tt(f);` is not able to create a new thread. Do you have any idea? Or any other method?

Comment: Please fully describe the expected behaviour and the actual behaviour. Provide a full, self contained example that just compiles. It's unlikely you simply start tt and do nothing with it.

Comment: Threading is not related to access visibility.

Comment: @gd1 with the reason of secret I can not provide the ful example. There is no error on compiling. In debug window of VS2010 I saw , the thread tt is not created while the thread t is successfully created.

Comment: In fact, you have to build a self-contained example which demonstrates the issue you are describing. Google for SSCCE. Providing code examples that don't compile (and that's not the subject of the question) annoys people.

Comment: @gd1 thank u for the advice. I do it next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

First of all, please provide a minimal, compilable example next time, e.g.

```
#include <functional>
#include <thread>

class A
{
    public:
        int memberfunction() { return 0; }
};

void D ()
{
    A x;
    std::function<int()> f;
    f = std::bind(&A::memberfunction, &x);   
    std::thread tt(f);
    tt.join();
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(D);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

(Compile with g++ -std=c++11 -pthread file.cpp)

Please note that I replaced `boost::thread` with `std::thread` and `boost::bind` with `std::bind` and that I am assuming that both are the same.

I also inserted some `join` calls. The destructor of `std::thread` throws an exception if your thread is still `joinable()`. This is the case if you did not call `join` or `detach`.

Not really related, but you should avoid using keywords for anything else, i.e. do not name your variables `class`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  The thread tt is created. I work on a big Project in a Company and I can not provide the original code therefor  I rewrite it. You are right, in next time I provide a example that can be compiled.